# How to add a stylesheet to the layout's head of a HAML template in Sinatra?

Tags: sinatra, haml

I'm searching for a way to add a stylesheet link to the layout's head of a HAML template.

My layout:

```
!!!
  %html
    %head
      / some stuffs
    %body
      = yield
```

My yielded template:

```
/ some other stuffs...

/maybe a function like this in order to inject 'my_stylesheet' link in layout
= content_for_head 'my_stylesheet'
```

Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: Add it to your head: `%link href="/path/to/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet"`

Comment: the thing is i don't want all the views that shared this layout have this stylesheet loaded

Comment: How do you determine which views get the stylesheet and which don't? Is there a pattern?

Comment: i would like to be able to link view specific stylesheet in the view code instead of in the layout code (since i don't want all my views have this stylesheet loaded)

Comment: for the moment i link directly in the body (in my view code), but it seems to be a bad pratice

Comment: Yeah, that is bad practice. You could maybe pass a local into each template, and in the layout output the stylesheet if the local is present.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can go about it. One is to use Sinatra's own [**`content_for`**](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/content_for.html) gem, or bundle ActionView, which will give you access to Rails' `content_for` method.

The second option is to do a manual check in the layout, and include the CSS there:

```ruby
# in your HAML template:
- if request.path_info == '/hello-world'
    %link{:rel => :stylesheet, :type => :"text/css", :href => "/assets/css/my_stylesheet"}
```